# Скачивание файла docx и csv через python

Tags: python, django

Делаю веб-приложение на django. У меня есть код, который формирует документы в формате csv и docx

csv:

```
FILENAME = "Статистика по продажам.csv"
with open(FILENAME, "w", newline="") as file:
    columns = ["Date","Price"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    i = 0
    a = 0
    while i<len(date):
        while a < len(price):
            users = [
                {"Date": date[i],"Price": price[a]},
            ]
            writer.writerows(users)
            i+=1
            a+=1
```

docx:

```
doc = DocxTemplate('template.docx')

    dates = date
    prices = price

    # Формируем список вида
    # [{'expirationdate': '2021-04-30', 'price': 1500},
    #  {'expirationdate': '2021-05-02', 'price': 450}, ...]
    tbl_contents = [{'expirationdate': expirationdate, 'price': price}
                    for expirationdate, price in zip(dates, prices)]

    context = {
        'tbl_contents': tbl_contents,
        'finalprice': sum(prices)
    }

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save("Static.docx")
```

Мне необходимо скачать эти файлы на устройства пользователей. Как это сделать?